# How do I exclude the patch header with "git diff"?

Tags: git

For example in the below output of `git diff`

```
diff --git a/commands.txt b/commands.txt
index 79e881a..a9588e5 100644
--- a/commands.txt
+++ b/commands.txt
@@ -1,3 +1,7 @@
+this is an example
+abcxyz
+helllo
+wooo
 makeFilePermissionExecutable
 makeOwnedByMyself
 makeFilePermissionEverything
```

Is it possible to hide the following:

```
diff --git a/commands.txt b/commands.txt
index 79e881a..a9588e5 100644
--- a/commands.txt
+++ b/commands.txt
```

And instead just show the filename (commands.txt in this case) instead?

Comment: The answer to the question can be "`git diff` has no such an option, so you have to find some workaround." And the answer by @mkrufky is quite an adequate workaround.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A workaround I found:

Make the following file accessible in your PATH:

**customGitDiff**

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo "$(tput setaf 4) $1"
echo -n "$(tput setaf 4)"
printf "%$(tput cols)s"|tr ' ' '-'
diff -u "$1" "$2" | tail -n +3 | colordiff
echo ""
```

Then you can instruct git to use the following script as your diff tool. It can be globally set by setting the following in your `~/.gitconfig`:

```
[diff]
  external = customGitDiff
```

One possibly unfortunate limitation of this, is I'm not sure if it uses the same diff algorithm as git diff.

The above provides me with the following output:
[image]

Comment: A much more aesthetic alternative might be: https://github.com/so-fancy/diff-so-fancy

Answer (score 8):

`git diff | tail -n +5` will produce the output that you desire.

We pipe the output of `git diff` into `tail -n +5` to begin output on line 5.  See the `man` page for `tail -n`:

```
   -n, --lines=[+]NUM
          output the last NUM lines, instead of the last  10;  or  use  -n
          +NUM to output starting with line NUM
```

You'll have to do some additional regex work if you're looking to consolidate `--- a/commands.txt` and `+++ b/commands.txt` to a single line.

Comment: This answer will not work appropriately when multiple files are changed.

Comment: I see what you mean.  `git diff` itself doesn't offer any option to show the diff while completely omitting all headers.  However, `git` is open source.  You can add the functionality that you want to your own fork of the git repository, located at https://github.com/git/git

Comment: That may be true but then the answer to every single question of the form "can I make software X do Y" when X is open source is going to be "yes". I'm pretty sure the OP's question came with the intrinsic clause of "without writing my own git client".

Answer (score 4):

```
git diff etc \
| sed '/^diff /,/^@@\|Binary/ {
    H;/^@@\|Binary/!d;z;x
    s".*\n--- a/\([^\n]*.\)+++ b/\1"==> File: \1"
}
'
```

That's "accumulate all lines in blocks starting `^diff`  and ending `^@@` or `^Binary`, and if the file isn't new or binary reformat the header".