# How to format the output of git diff

Tags: git

Is it possible to format the output of git diff so I'll get only the actual text difference?

for example, this is the default git diff output:

```
diff --git a/diff_test.txt b/diff_test.txt
index 6b0c6cf..b37e70a 100644
--- a/diff_test.txt
+++ b/diff_test.txt
@@ -1 +1 @@
-this is a git diff test example
+this is a diff example
```

Instead I want to get:

```
diff --git a/diff_test.txt b/diff_test.txt
-this is a git diff test example
+this is a diff example
```

is it possible with git diff or other git command **without** using other scripts like shell, python ,etc?

Comment: Did you read https://git-scm.com/docs/diff-format?

Comment: I did, couldn't find a way to get rid of the headers. if you see the answer there, please post as an answer to my question.

Comment: if you are on bash, you can skip the first 4 header lines by piping to sed. for ex. git diff ... | sed 1,4d

Comment: thanks @StPiere , but I'm trying to figure out it it's possible without bash.

Comment: I dont think there is a git diff option to do that. You have to use a pipe.

Comment: "without using bash tricks" seems to indicate you intend to apply it on systems without bash : can you please add your intention in your question (explain the context in which you would like to produce such diffs) ? instead of `sed` (which can also be run from cmd.exe or powershell btw), you can use any scripting language : python or perl, for example, are pretty common on all platforms, and often already installed because other tools need them.

Comment: I meant with using git diff or other git commands and not using other scripts. 
("not possible" can also be an answer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Excluding a diff patch header](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47496283/6309) involves generally shell commands (`tail/sed`)

You can only limit the [context to only the modified line](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18810673/6309), but anything more, like hiding/remove the hunk headers, [as in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62009746/6309), will involve some "non-git" command.